# Getting the value of FailedPasswordAttemptCount from the object model, not database

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I am trying to get the `FailedPasswordAttemptCount` from the ASP.NET built in objects and I am not able to find one, is there any way I can get this value without creating a new storedProc?

Excuse me if the question is redundant.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only one function of buil-in `SqlMembershipProvider` uses this property I found is:

```
private void GetPasswordWithFormat(string username, bool updateLastLoginActivityDate, out int status, out string password, out int passwordFormat, out string passwordSalt, out int failedPasswordAttemptCount, out int failedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount, out bool isApproved, out DateTime lastLoginDate, out DateTime lastActivityDate)
```

it's private. Thus the best solution is to override the existed one, and roll your own with addition method to gather the data you need, e.g.:

```
public class MySqlMembershipProvider : SqlMembershipProvider
{
    public int GetFailedPasswordAttemptCount (Guid userId)
    {
        // SELECT FailedPasswordAttemptCount FROM aspnet_Membership WHERE UserId = UserId
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var count = ((MySqlMembershipProvider)System.Web.Security.Membership.Provider).GetFailedPasswordAttemptCount(...);
```

Comment: You can solve this with reflection without worrying about the DB
 public int GetFailedPasswordAttemptCount(string email)
        {
            var method = typeof(SqlMembershipProvider).GetMethod("GetPasswordWithFormat", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            if (method != null)
            {
                var pars = new object[] { email, false, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null };

                var res = method.Invoke(this, pars);

                return (int)pars[6];
            }

            return 0;
        }